# Problems with D&D game

Tags: python

This is the main that will call everything

```
import GameClass

def main ():
    game = GameClass
    game.Run()
    #GameClass.Run()

main()
```

When running the `main` function that calls everything it came out with the error:"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\D & D game\D&D game.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\D & D game\D&D game.py", line 10, in main
    game.Run()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Run'
```

Not totally sure what to do.

`GameClass` that it is calling

```
import random

import EnemyBaseClass
import PlayerClass
import OgreClass
import TrollClass
import DragonClass
import GoblinClass

#Game Class

class GameClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.PlayerCharacter = PlayerClass.Player()
        self.Location = ['You have entered the frozen slopes of the ice everyglades',
                         'You have entered the enchanted forest of the elves',
                         'You decided to enter the dragons mountains',
                         'you saild across the frozen seas of everyfrost',
                         'Your home has become covered ina thick fog',
                         'You come across a small village']
        self.Score = 0
        self.Enemies = [TrollClass.Troll(), OgreClass.Ogre(), DragonClass.Dragon(),      GoblinClass.Goblin()]
    self.EnemySelected = self.Enemies[0]

def PlayerAttack(self):
    self.PlayerCharacter.DetermineDamage()
    self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].Life -= self.PlayerCharacter.Damage

    if self.PlayerCharacter.Damage == 0:
        print("The player Goes for a strike but misses.")
    else:
        print("The player attacks and Does " +str(self.PlayerCharacter.Damage) + "damage.")
        self.Score +=10

    print("The " + self.Enemies[self.EnemiesSelected].Name + " now has " + str(self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].Life))

def EnemyAttack(self):
    self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].DetermineDamage()
    self.PlayerCharacter.Life -= self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].Damage

    if self.Enemies[self.EnemiesSelected].Damage == 0:
        print("The " + self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].Name + " goes for a strike but misses.")
    else:
        print("The " + self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].Name + " attacks and does " + str(self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].Damage) + "damage.")

    print("The player now has " + str(self.PlayerCharacter.Life) + " life left.")

def Battle (self):

        print ("A Great battle begins!")
        self.EnemySelected = random.randint ( 0, len(self.Location) - 1 )
        self.Enemies[self.EnemySelected].DetermineLife()
        while self.PlayerCharacter.life > 0 and self.Enemies[self.EnemySeleced].Life > 0:
            self.PlayerAttack()
            self.EnemyAttack()

def TravelToLocation(self):
        print (self.Location[random.randint( 0, len(self.Location) - 1 )])

def Login(self):
          print("You must login to play the game")

def ReadFile(self):
        print ("Readig File")

def VerifyLogin(self):
        print("Saving your game")

def WriteFile(self):
        print("Saving You Game")

def Over(self):
        print ("Game Over Your Score was " + Str(self.Score_ + "Points"))

def Run(self):

    while self.PlayerCharacter.GetLife() > 0:
            self.PlayerCharacter.Upkeep()
            self.TravelToLocation()
            self.Battle()

    self.WriteFile()
    self.Over()
```

Comment: Can you properly format your code and do not use "LARGE TEXT"? Thanks.

Comment: Could you **ask an actual question**, please? Provide the full error traceback. Why aren't you *instantiating* `GameClass`?

Comment: maybe try `game = GameClass()`

Comment: when running:    game = GameClass() it says it is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Re-read the traceback:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Run'
```

You `import` the **module** `GameClass`, *within which* is the **class** `GameClass`. You want to instantiate and call methods on *the latter*. Either:

```
import GameClass # import the module

GameClass.GameClass().Run() # access class via module
```

or:

```
from GameClass import GameClass # import class

GameClass().Run() # access class directly
```

Or, if you followed Python's [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```
from game import Game

Game().run()
```